# Receiving a speech signal input from Bluetooth to Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, signal-processing

We're looking at creating an Android app that takes a speech signal from a Bluetooth headset. We'd like to apply some digital signal processing to the signal and output it through the Android phone speakers themselves, I'm having a hard time finding info on sending Bluetooth data into an app. After the device has been located and paired, how can I work with input?